# Using R to find correlation pairs

Tags: r, correlation

```
           VZ.Close CBOU.Close SBUX.Close   T.Close
VZ.Close   1.0000000  0.5804478  0.8872978 0.9480894
CBOU.Close 0.5804478  1.0000000  0.7876277 0.4988890
SBUX.Close 0.8872978  0.7876277  1.0000000 0.8143305
T.Close    0.9480894  0.4988890  0.8143305 1.0000000
```

So, Let's say I have these correlations between stock prices.  I would like to look at the first row and find the pair with the highest correlation.  That would be VZ and T.  I then want to remove those 2 stocks as options.  Then, among the remaining stocks find the pair with the highest correlation.  And so on until all stocks are paired.  In this example it would obviously be CBOU and SBUX because they are the only 2 left, but I want the code able to accommodate any number of pairs.

Comment: Why do you only look at the first row in the first step ? Don't you want to find the higher correlation among all the rows instead ?

Comment: The question is a bit ambiguous and needs better explanation. Do you want to remove those two stocks as options in the first row ( i.e. the stock relating to the first row itself and the stock with the next greatest correlation), and then return out of the remaining stocks, no matter how many there may be, the two that have the greatest correlation in the first row (i.e. greatest correlation with VZ.close in this example), and do this for each row?

Comment: This question is not related to stocks: it's purely a matter of evaluating matches in rows of a matrix.  I'm not sure this is a good use of the term "correlation," as it appears you just want to find the 2 values in a given row which are closest to each other. In that case, @SimonO101 's answer looks pretty good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution if you want to look at the maximum correlation at each step. So the first step will not look only at the first row, but at the whole matrix.

Sample data :

```
d <- matrix(runif(36),ncol=6,nrow=6)
rownames(d) <- colnames(d) <- LETTERS[1:6]
diag(d) <- 1
d
           A          B         C          D         E          F
A 1.00000000 0.65209204 0.8520392 0.26980214 0.5844000 0.69335143
B 0.73531603 1.00000000 0.5499431 0.60511580 0.7483990 0.14788134
C 0.56433218 0.27242769 1.0000000 0.07952776 0.2147628 0.03711562
D 0.91756919 0.04853523 0.5554490 1.00000000 0.4344089 0.23381447
E 0.06897889 0.80740821 0.7974340 0.87425643 1.0000000 0.74546072
F 0.19961474 0.61665231 0.2829632 0.58110694 0.7433924 1.00000000
```

And the code :

```
results <- data.frame(v1=character(0), v2=character(0), cor=numeric(0), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
diag(d) <- 0
while (sum(d>0)>1) {
  maxval <- max(d)
  max <- which(d==maxval, arr.ind=TRUE)[1,]
  results <- rbind(results, data.frame(v1=rownames(d)[max[1]], v2=colnames(d)[max[2]], cor=maxval))
  d[max[1],] <- 0
  d[,max[1]] <- 0
  d[max[2],] <- 0
  d[,max[2]] <- 0
}
```

Which gives :

```
  v1 v2       cor
1  D  A 0.9175692
2  E  B 0.8074082
3  F  C 0.2829632
```

Comment: I used this basic format.  Whenever I get stock correlations, below the diagonal is just a mirror image of above the diagonal.  So I turned the lower triangle of the matrix into zeros also.  Sometimes, stock correlations are negative numbers.  So, to solve that problem I created a function that looks for the maximum value in a matrix, ignoring all zeros and used it instead of max(d).  Then I changed the while loop to iterate until sum(d != 0)>0.  It seems to serve the purpose!    Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think this answers your question, but I can't be sure as the original question is a bit ambiguous...

```
# Construct toy example of symmentrical matrix
# nc is number of rows/columns in matrix, in the problem above it was 4, but let's try with 6
nc <- 6
mat <- diag( 1 , nc )
# Create toy correlation data for matrix
dat <- runif( ( (nc^2-nc)/2 ) )
# Fill both triangles of matrix so it is symmetric
mat[lower.tri( mat ) ] <- dat 
mat[upper.tri( mat ) ] <- dat

# Create vector of random string names for row/column names
names <- replicate( nc , expr = paste( sample( c( letters , LETTERS ) , 3 , replace = TRUE ) , collapse = "" ) )
dimnames(mat) <- list( names , names )

# Sanity check
mat
    SXK   llq   xFL   RVW   oYQ   Seb
SXK 1.000 0.973 0.499 0.585 0.813 0.751
llq 0.973 1.000 0.075 0.533 0.794 0.826
xFL 0.499 0.099 1.000 0.099 0.481 0.968
RVW 0.075 0.813 0.620 1.000 0.620 0.307
oYQ 0.585 0.794 0.751 0.968 1.000 0.682
Seb 0.533 0.481 0.826 0.307 0.682 1.000

# Ok - to problem at hand , you can just substitute your matrix into these lines:
# Clearly the diagonal in a correlation matrix will be 1 so this is excluded as per your problem
diag( mat ) <- NA
# Now find the next highest correlation in each row and set this to NA
mat <- t( apply( mat , 1 , function(x) { x[ which.max(x) ] <- NA ; return(x) } ) ) 

# Another sanity check...!
mat

      SXK   llq   xFL   RVW   oYQ   Seb
SXK    NA    NA 0.499 0.585 0.813 0.751
llq    NA    NA 0.075 0.533 0.794 0.826
xFL 0.499 0.099    NA 0.099 0.481    NA
RVW 0.075    NA 0.620    NA 0.620 0.307
oYQ 0.585 0.794 0.751    NA    NA 0.682
Seb 0.533 0.481    NA 0.307 0.682    NA


# Now return the two remaining columns with greatest correlation in that row
res <- t( apply( mat , 1 , function(x) { y <- names( sort(x , TRUE ) )[1:2] ; return( y ) } ) )

res


[,1]  [,2] 
SXK "oYQ" "Seb"
llq "Seb" "oYQ"
xFL "SXK" "oYQ"
RVW "xFL" "oYQ"
oYQ "llq" "xFL"
Seb "oYQ" "SXK"
```

Does this answer your question?